the virtual scroll CDK with dynamic size (Angular 18)
I use CDK virtual scroll to optimize the display of my data. I've even tested CDK experimental with autosizing, which obviously doesn't work in Angular 18.
My items have a minimum size of 26px, which varies depending on the content. So I can't know in advance what size the item will be.
Do you have any ideas for my code?


<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport [itemSize]="getItemSize()" class="viewport-container">

  <div *cdkVirtualFor="let category of categoryArraySignal();  trackBy: trackByCategoryName;"
       style="display: flex" [ngClass]="{'hightlighted': lastSelectedCategoryEvent === category}">

    <div (click)="selectCategory(category)" class="category-container"
         [ngStyle]=" {'height': timeLineService.calculateHeightCellForCategoryItem(timeLineEvents, category.categoryName) + 'px '}">
      <div class="category-item">
        {{ category.categoryName }}
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="isTimeLineEventsContainsStormEvent(timeLineService.getTimeLineEventsForCategoryName(category.categoryName, timeLineEvents))"
           class="container-storm-icon">
        <mat-icon svgIcon="Storm" class="storm-icon" [ngClass]="getStormIconColor(category.categoryName)"></mat-icon>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div style="width: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
      <div class="row-container">
        <div *ngFor="let categoryContainer of getCategoryContainerByCategoryName(category.categoryName)">
          <div style=" height:26px; width: 100%; display: flex"
               *ngFor="let rowContent of  categoryContainer.rows.rowContent">
            <div *ngFor="let timeLineEvent of rowContent.timeEventsInRow">
              <app-timeline-event [timeLineEvent]="timeLineEvent"
                                  [componentForTooltip]="componentForTooltip"
                                  [isActivateBorderColor]="isActivateBorderColor"></app-timeline-event>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>



I can get the size of each item with the calculateHeightCellForCategoryItem method, but I don't know how to do it.
